# Can't select Application in EMV card using valid AID

Tags: apdu, emv

I have both a Visa Electron and Debit Mastercard, however whenever i try to select the Application using their respective AIDs A0000000032010 and A0000000041010  I get a 6A82 response meaning the file was not found.

Here's my code snippet for both selections

```
//SELECTING VISA ELECRON CARD APPLICATION
byte[] ApduCMDVC = new byte[] {  (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x04,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0E,
            (byte) 0x41, (byte)0x30, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x30,
            (byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x30,
            (byte) 0x33,(byte) 0x32,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x31,(byte) 0x30};

//SELECTING MASTER CARD APPLICATION
byte[] ApduCMDMC = new byte[] {  (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x04,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0E,
            (byte) 0x41, (byte)0x30, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x30,
            (byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x30,
            (byte) 0x34,(byte) 0x31,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x31,(byte) 0x30};
```

Could there be something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, how are you issuing the APDUs? Java? Jacal? Also, can  you post a code snippet, all you are showing is the byte array for the AIDs.

Comment: Hi Greycon, yes I'm using Java, I am developing a mobile pos app for android and I have an sdk from the card reader manufacturers that sends the apdu commands to the card reader, So I am basically sending the apdu commands as byte arrays. The snippet I pasted earlier is from my code only thing missing is the method that sends the request to the card reader.

Comment: OK, I have some Java code that does this, it's a few years old - standby while I go hunting. I presume you did the select of the "Payfile.sys" or whatever it is first?

Comment: Thanks a lot Greycon, I'll be expecting the code. I skipped the selection of 1PAY.SYS.DDF01 because some cards especially the Visa Electron doesn't support the application. So I'm just going straight to selecting by AID. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked back at some C++ code I used for this in the past, and I believe your problem is that you are sending the AID in ASCII, as opposed to binary. Here's the C++ byte array I use:

```
static  BYTE    selectAIDCmd[] = {0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x07, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x10, 0x10 };
```

So, you need this:

```
    byte[] ApduCMDMC = new byte[] {  (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x04,
        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x07,
        (byte) 0xA0, (byte)0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte)0x03,(byte) 0x20,(byte) 0x10};
```

Comment: I don't think so Greycon because I am casting the hex values to bytes before sending it.

Comment: That's why I asked you to post code. I can't guess what you are doing? The byte array I posted is one from a working C++ program. And "Casting hex values to bytes" makes no sense. Can you please post the code, up to, and including the APDU Send call?

Comment: Oh, you mean you do: "(byte)0x30" - This just tells the compiler that this is a single byte, but it's value will still be Hex 30. What is required is (byte)0x00.   Completely different animal.

Comment: Just try it, trust me. For your AID, instead of 0x41, 0x30, etc, use 0xA0, 0x00, etc. It will work.

Comment: Hi Jide, could you edit your original post and add the amended byte array? I'll try to do the same with my definition... standby, we will get it working.

Comment: I'm getting a compiler error as expected after trying your suggestion Greycon. [br]Here's a snippet.  `byte[] ApduCMDVC =  new byte[] {  (byte) 0x00,  0xA4, 0x04,
                 0x00,  0x0E,
                 0x41, 0x30,  0x30,  0x30,
                 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30,
                0x33, 0x32, 0x30,0x31, 0x30};

        messager.ApduCmd(ApduCMDVC);`  Possible loss of precision required byte, found: int

Comment: Hi Jide, you still need to cast to (byte), see my modified answer. What I was trying to say earlier was that casting 0x30 to (byte)0x30 will not change the value, so the code will pass a 0x30 byte to the API, when in face a 0x00 value needs to be passed. 0x30 is the ASCII representation for 0.

Comment: Okay @Greycon I'll try what you posted.

Comment: just tried your suggestion, still getting the 6A82 response.

Comment: So, basically, while the ASCII representation of you AID is 14 bytes, the binary representation is only 7 bytes, please see my amended answer...

Comment: your modified answer worked perfectly for both Master card and Visa, I am getting the expected responses now. Could you please send me your email? Need to have a discussion with you privately.